# Ubuntu Server (Home Server): LVM Encrypted VS Unencrypted

Tags: server, encryption

I have a machine running as a Home Server for Samba, streaming with Kodi, Torrent and Webmin. Actually is running Ubuntu Mate 16.04. I was thinking of switching to Ubuntu Server because I want to do a fresh install and setup everything again removing everything I have tested and to have a "stable" server just running the things I need in addition to finally remove the desktop environment that I don't really need/use. I know what I have to do but (finally) my question is: should I use disk encryption (or home encryption) or not?

I have this server mostly for media and some other documents and stuff to share between the home network only. I don't really have anything important or really private that I want to hide, but it's my practice that I have always used disk encryption on all my machines. I ask because in a home server is a little different. Every time I have to make a restart I need to put the password and if is Home Encryption is the same thing; to use over the network I have to login to connects other machines to the samba server. I want to know the Pros and Cons of Disk Encryption in a home server and Home Encryption. It is really convenient? How does affect the performance? Should I just use disk encryption and forget about home encryption?

Thank you in advance for your answers.

Comment: You don't really have anything important or really private (in the server). So I suggest that you don't encrypt it at all. It is more difficult to recover an encrypted system. Focus on other aspects of security, for example to avoid risky web sites and manage passwords carefully.

Comment: I'm  not worried about data recover. I do regular backups (once a month at least) and in case of anything going wrong, data corruption or something like that, I just create a new server and restore my backup. What I'm worried is that in case of someone stealing my PC (hypothetically), then (in theory) they could see everything I have: personal pictures, videos, etc., and that is never something good.

Comment: In that case I think encrypted disk alias LVM with encryption is the best alternative.